# Laravel return data by sort

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, sorting

I have problem to returning json data and `sort` them in `laravel`, they just appear randomly.

## What I did so far

1. I tried to return data by their `id` from database and help of
   JavaScript like:

   `result.sort(function(a,b) {
     return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);
   });`
   Result was random order (sort)
2. I added `sort` column to my database and tried to get my data base on numbers I provided there (result was random order)
3. I tried to add `->orderByRaw('set_specification.sort')` in my function code and get orders by that (result was random order)

## Logic

1. I select a `set`
2. `Set` child's will appear on blade by `sort` column order which I
   provide numbers in it.

## Code

`controller`

```
public function selectset($id){
      $selectsets = DB::table('sets')
        ->where('sets.id', '=', $id)
        ->join('set_specification', 'sets.id', '=', 'set_specification.set_id')
        ->join('specifications', 'set_specification.spec_id', '=', 'specifications.id')
        ->orderByRaw('set_specification.sort')
        ->get();
      return response()->json($selectsets);
    }
```

`JavaScript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(result) {


          result.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);
          });

          console.log(result);

//rest of code..
}
```

## Issues

Even when I return my data by help of ajax sort (as you see in my code) in console it returns correctly but in blade it appears as it wish!

[image: screenone]

in case image above won't work [here it is again](https://ibb.co/cj8qJU)

## Question

1. How can I fix this sorting issue?

## Update

I changed my ajax code to:

```
result.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (a.sort > b.sort) ? 1 : ((b.sort > a.sort) ? -1 : 0);
});
```

and result is the same [screenshot](https://ibb.co/hKzVJU)

Comment: What is the type of your `sort` column in the database? I'm guessing it's not an integer. And if you're sorting by `id`, you need to specify the table, because you're joining multiple different tables.

Comment: no is varchar :)

Comment: Change it to an integer.

Comment: i'll try.......

Comment: _"There is no try, only do, or do not"_ - Yoda

Comment: i thought the same, but why would it sort it as: 1, 11, 2, 4, 3

Comment: @Erubiel, I think the screenshot is ordered by `id`, whereas the code suggests OP wants to ordered by `sort`, which appears to be a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: It's that the screenshot for your sort callback `return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0);`  or for the one i wrote in the answers?

Comment: @fubar didn't work https://ibb.co/hKzVJU

Comment: I think your DB records are wrong, that's the expected behavior... sort 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: @Erubiel updated my question

Comment: I don't get the problem now, your sort column is doing what you wanted, the rest of the columns are not changing, as i said before, i think you gotta update your db records... @fubar what do u think?

Comment: @mafortis - what is not working? The screenshot shows the data correctly ordered by the `sort` field. Your question talks about `sort` and `id`. Update your question to be **clear** which field you want to sort by.

Comment: @Erubiel update my database how? you mean changing my column to integer? i did that already based on `fubar` suggestion.

Comment: @fubar see the blade, as i said in my question `in console it returns correctly but in blade it appears as it wish!`

Comment: I mean, your records might be wrong, the actual data on your rows, not the structure... the data... `id: 3, name: "title", sort: 1`... how are those records inserted? did you added manually? maybe you put some sort value in the wrong row...

Comment: @mafortis, where is your controller and Blade code?

Comment: @Erubiel this is my database https://ibb.co/fLXgsp (except `sort` the rest are dynamically (added by multiple select) )

Comment: @fubar controller I shared already in my question, for the blade in same ajax as you see and data will add by `append`.

Comment: @mafortis, sorry I cannot follow what your code currently looks like. Your query is ordering by `sort`, yet your AJAX callback is ordering by `id`??!

Comment: Lets forget about your table a little... if i have three rows A B C, and i want to sort em by a Sort column like you... and i want them sorted in that order... i have to do something like A 1, B 2, C 3... if i do A 2, B 3, C 1, they will return sorted as C A B... Are you not doing something like this in any of your rows, since you added the sort value manually and you are only seeing IDs, you might have inserted the wrong sort, value, do you understand my question now?

Comment: @fubar that the exact issue that i'm facing that's why i made this question :). thanks anyway for sharing ideas.

Comment: @Erubiel honestly i'm a bit in dark now, all i know is that i provided numbers `1-12` in my sort column and it returning correctly in console but somehow it doesn't in blade, WHY? i don't know :/ (anyway here is my full javascript code for this function maybe you can find something useful in it https://www.codepile.net/pile/RlQoa6Dk)

Comment: Dude, i know whats wrong with your code now, ajax is asynchronus and your data is appended when the request is responded which might not be in the same order that requests are made...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you provided in the comments: https://www.codepile.net/pile/RlQoa6Dk

You are appending the data to the html on the ajax response, remember that ajax is asynchronous, so although your ajax requests are made in order, the responses might not happen in that order.

Thats why you always get random orders...

<s>You should:</s>

1. Do the first ajax call
2. foreach element in the response, make the second ajax call
3. append the calculated html for each element in the response
4. Once every ajax call is terminated, or at least the multiple ajax calls to calculate the html, order the original response which by now has the html.
5. foreach element in the response, append the calculated html

**Edit**

Just appending the row before doing the ajax call worked.

```js
<script defer>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(result) {
                    $('div#dataaamsg').empty();
                    $('div#dataaamsg').append('Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button to select multiple options');
                    result.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return (a.sort > b.sort) ? 1 : ((b.sort > a.sort) ? -1 : 0);
                    });

                    $.each(result, function(key1, value1) {

                        var vvvid = value1.id;

                        if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }else if(value1['type'] == 'textareafield'){
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }else{
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }

                        // second data
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ url('admin/findsubspecification') }}/'+value1['id'],
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:function(data) {
                                // Check result isnt empty
                                var helpers = '';
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    helpers += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
                                });

                                if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><input id="text_dec" name="text_dec[]" placeholder="text field" class="text_dec form-control"></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }else if(value1['type'] == 'textareafield'){
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><textarea id="longtext_dec" name="longtext_dec[]" placeholder="text area field" class="longtext_dec form-control"></textarea></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }else{
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><select class="subspecifications form-control tagsselector" id="subspecifications" name="subspecifications[]" multiple="multiple">'+helpers+'</select></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="sendspacsdatato" class="sendspacsdatato btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }


                            }
                        });
                        // second data

                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('div#dataaa').empty();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that it didn't work, (worked as i explained in issue section) so i decided to share original code.

Comment: @mafortis im 100% sure this is the problem with the code.

Comment: it stops rendering my data in blade (i just get white space)

Comment: Weird, is there any error logged in the console / devTools ? This is the problem with your original code, you do understand the problem right?

Comment: If you don't understand the problem, you can go to devTools, open the network tab and refresh the page, see how your request are done and how they complete... you may trigger request 1,2,3,4,5 but server can respond 5,2,1,3,4... or any other order, thats why they call it asynchronous... and thats why your html is appended wrongly

Comment: network get full list with status of `200` but in console i have `TypeError: my_row is undefined`

Comment: try logging my_row, if some my_rows are not null and some are, and they change... there may be another race condition present...

Comment: One last approach before i go to sleep... check the edit, i append the row first, then do the ajax, then on success update the html of the row...

Comment: holy -------, it seems to be working :) i test it more and let you know.

Comment: It's working perfectly, honestly can't thank you enough... THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: hi bro this code of yours broke functionality of my code :\ is there any way we can talk about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179143/discussion-between-erubiel-and-mafortis).

Comment: I'm going out for a little bit, be back in a few hours, in the meantime, you can reply to me on chat, or open a new question and send it on chat also.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your code in controller like below

add one function

```
public function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['sort'], $b['sort']);
}
```

Update Your selectset function like below

```
public function selectset($id){
$selectsets = DB::table('sets')
    ->where('sets.id', '=', $id)
    ->join('set_specification', 'sets.id', '=', 'set_specification.set_id')
    ->join('specifications', 'set_specification.spec_id', '=', 'specifications.id')
    ->orderByRaw('set_specification.sort')
    ->get();
usort($selectsets, array($this, "cmp"));
return response()->json($selectsets);
}
```

Comment: hi, are you sure about `usort`? shouldn't have `$` anything?

Comment: Okay try it once

Comment: i am getting `SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'function'[Learn More]`

Comment: that was full error and here is detail of it`public function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->sort, $b->sort);
}`