# Collecting multiple data and send by ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax to send my data to controller and save it in database, before my code was working then I needed to sort my data when they append in blade after sorting them it stop working by %50.

> #### Good to know
>
> [Here is my old code and solution of sorting my data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067992/laravel-return-data-by-sort) (which caused
>   this issue that i have now)

## Logic

1. I select set
2. Set childs will append in blade (sorted by custom column)
3. I choose single or multiple options and hit save button
4. Data saves to database

## More to know

My appended data (based on selected set) are include 2 types of data

1. Custom inputs (text field & text-area field) which i can manually fill and save (**still working with no issue**)
2. Dynamic select option which returns from database and i can select and save their id's (**this is the issue dynamics**)

## Code

`Script of appending data`

```
<script defer>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(result) {
                    $('div#dataaamsg').empty();
                    $('div#dataaamsg').append('Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button to select multiple options');
                    result.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : ((b.position > a.position) ? -1 : 0);
                    });

                    $.each(result, function(key1, value1) {

                        var vvvid = value1.id;

                        if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }else if(value1['type'] == 'textareafield'){
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }else{
                            var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20">');
                            $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                        }

                        // second data
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ url('admin/findsubspecification') }}/'+value1['id'],
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:function(data) {
                                // Check result isnt empty
                                var helpers = '';
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    helpers += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
                                });

                                if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><input id="text_dec" name="text_dec[]" placeholder="text field" class="text_dec form-control"></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }else if(value1['type'] == 'textareafield'){
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_id" id="specification_id" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><textarea id="longtext_dec" name="longtext_dec[]" placeholder="text area field" class="longtext_dec form-control"></textarea></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsavee" class="custmodalsavee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }else{
                                    var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><select class="subspecifications form-control tagsselector" id="subspecifications" name="subspecifications[]" multiple="multiple">'+helpers+'</select></div>';
                                    my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="savedynspecto" class="savedynspecto btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                    my_row.html(my_html);
                                }


                            }
                        });
                        // second data

                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('div#dataaa').empty();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

`script of saving data (issue part)`

```
<script defer>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".savedynspecto", function(e){
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
      // e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}',
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': id,
          'subspecifications': $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert('Specifications added successfully.');
          console.log($(this));
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

## Issue

1. When I try to save my dynamic values i cannot get id of selected option/options

   //returned data in network params
   _token  g1GnKZvzXDztR1lqgDdjI5QOg67SfmmBhjm80fKu
   product_id  18
   subspecifications

**Ps1**

I've tried to change `val()` to `serialize()` and I got

```
_token g1GnKZvzXDztR1lqgDdjI5QOg67SfmmBhjm80fKu
product_id 18
subspecifications subspecifications%5B%5D=20&subspecifications%5B%5D=21&subspecifications%5B%5D=23&subspecifications%5B%5D=32"
```

All I needed was `21,23,32` instead i got `subspecifications%5B%5D=` before each of them.

**Ps2**

I've tried to change `$("body").on("click", ".savedynspecto", function(e){` that would not send any data to back-end (nothing prints in network not even error codes)

Any idea?

Comment: Can u console what u are getting in $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    helpers += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
                                });
in helper

Comment: can you please share sample results, generated by controllers with me ?

Comment: @ArashKhajelou hi, if i use serialize this is my result `array:3 [
  "_token" => "Ou5M0WwUziuG3h1WN3D0D2ND5nCtaKejZDUSEnwa"
  "product_id" => "21"
  "subspecifications" => "subspecifications%5B%5D=4&subspecifications%5B%5D=5&subspecifications%5B%5D=22"
]` if i use `val` this is the result `array:3 [
  "_token" => "Ou5M0WwUziuG3h1WN3D0D2ND5nCtaKejZDUSEnwa"
  "product_id" => "21"
  "subspecifications" => array:1 [
    0 => "3"
  ]
]` PS: the way val returns data is correct the issue with it is that only gets first row values when i have multiple row always return first one.

Answer (score 3):

Hi change this line in your code

> 'subspecifications':
>   $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val()

to

> 'subspecifications':
>   $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications
>   option:selected').map(function(){ return this.value }).get()

It should help

Comment: hi, thanks for the respond. it appears to be working however with this method it requires small changes which i'm not sure how to do it. `explanation` before each form sends selected options id and when i click save button it saves only those options that's why i had save button for each appended row in my blade, currently save button on any of these rows will send all selected options id from all rows, so i think it's better to have only 1 save button `in total` instead of 1 save button for each row. `Q` how can i make that happen?

Comment: for better understanding i made these images of before/after `1` https://ibb.co/hU1tpe `2` https://ibb.co/cpjDpe

Comment: If you want just one button for saving.
I think better way split selects and send them on server with different names.

Comment: how can i set different names? my data are dynamic could be any amount of rows.

Comment: Can you share with me:
1) Html of page 
2) Controller method

Comment: the html is basically everything in my script code because this is what will append to blade everything else is just `<div id="dataaa"></div>` for the controller please wait i share and give you the link.

Comment: here you go, this almost everything related to this part https://www.codepile.net/pile/NVgvk1Pz (i commented parts for you)

Comment: So how I understand you need update relation between product and subspecifications 

For each select on page we have different product ?

Comment: Not sure if i get your point but I'm open to any suggestions, please share your solution we see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

After the button... in the string to append, you have `{{Form::close()}}</div>`.

I think the `</div>` should come before the `{{Form::close()}}`.

A messed-up HTML structure can lead to strangenesses quickly.
I'm not 100% sure that is the issue... But it could.

Comment: still sending `subspecifications` empty as my `issue` part i shared the code

Comment: okay...  My other idea is to try to remove the brackets `[]` in `name="subspecifications[]"` because the output of a `<select multiple>` already is an array...

Comment: yet getting empty `subspecifications`

Comment: mmm... Before the Ajax request (which you can commented out just for tests), try those console.logs: `console.log( $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').length );` and `console.log( $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val() )`.

Comment: serialize would get id's but i don't know why has extra `subspecifications%5B%5D=`

Comment: it returns this but the issue is getting same `subspecifications`  for all my saves no matter single option or multiple https://www.codepile.net/pile/6LN02zpl

Comment: I lost you... Does the first console.log returned `1` (so we're sure the element is found) And does the second shows an array with correct values?

Comment: my bad apologize again, the result of your console codes: `length` 15, `val` null

Comment: `15` !!! Ahhh... Ok. There is way more than one select having the `.subspecifications` class then.

Comment: I realized something, i checked my local version (before sort results) and online version (which we working on now) the old version after row opens i have `<form....>` but in new verion i don't have form tag i just have my hidden inputs.. could be something related to that?

Comment: I can't tell... I made you a quick [example](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GXWKPp?editors=1111) on what you should try to gather all the selects values in one array. If it works, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks but there is one issue as i have 3 type of inputs sometimes between my select options i have input fields so is that possible i make form around my select boxes? https://ibb.co/bVfiEe  i mean later my inputs form goes middle of my select boxes forms (form in form is not valid) that's why i have form and separate save button for each of my appended data.

Comment: The `select.subspecifications` gets a collection of elements. The form doesn't matter here. The issue is `.val()` will only get the value of the first element in collection. That's why you have to loop through them.

Comment: Hello @mafortis can you try to see request of ps1 in controller via `dd(request()->all());`  i think you will get your needed requests.

Comment: Hello @KevalMangukiya this is what i get with serialize (ps1)  `array:3 [
  "_token" => "Ou5M0WwUziuG3h1WN3D0D2ND5nCtaKejZDUSEnwa"
  "product_id" => "21"
  "subspecifications" => "subspecifications%5B%5D=4&subspecifications%5B%5D=5&subspecifications%5B%5D=22"
]`

Answer (score 0):

You have MANY `select` with class `subspecifications`... So you have to loop through them to get their values.

```
<script defer>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".savedynspecto", function(e){
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();

      // An array to store the subspecifications values.
      var spec_array = [];

      // A loop to go through all them.
      form.find('select.subspecifications').each(function(){
        spec_array.push($(this).val());
      });

      // e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}',
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': id,
          'subspecifications': spec_array  // The array containing each SELECT values
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert('Specifications added successfully.');
          console.log($(this));
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this is what i get with this code, `error 500` + `_token Ou5M0WwUziuG3h1WN3D0D2ND5nCtaKejZDUSEnwa
product_id 21
subspecifications[] 
subspecifications[3][] 199
subspecifications[4][] […]
0 204
1 205`

Comment: [Error 500](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error)? I cant' tell.. That is due to the code you have on the ressource called by Ajax. That is, **for sure**, another problem. Now you have some data sent about each SELECT, which is good... And that was the topic of your question.

Comment: thanks anyway man, i see if others have another solutions :/ confused by this